# how to set up run tests at ci pipeline with storybook and github actions

Tags: reactjs, testing, continuous-integration, storybook

I have been learning to work with tests in storykook using [interaction addon](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/essentials/interactions).
But i don't know how to run tests before push at main branch(make deploy), A way i found is running all the tests using git hook(pre-puch), but **run all test isn't a good choice** when my app grow up and **i want to use pipeline ci/cd instead git hooks**

Thanks for read!

you can found that app [here](https://github.com/Matheus8174/boilerplate-sb-next-tailwind-typescript)

Answer (score 6):

i find an answer

basically you need create a script in your package.json thats run that code

```bash
concurrently -k -s first -n \"SB,TEST\" -c \"magenta,blue\" \"npm run storybook:build --quiet && npx http-server storybook-static --port 6006 --silent\" \"wait-on tcp:6006 && npm run storybook:test\"
```

dont forget to install concurrently wait-on and http-server.
And run this script in your ci job.

you can check out [that](https://github.com/Matheus8174/boilerplate-sb-next-tailwind-typescript) repository to find an example

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/test-runner#running-in-ci

Comment: Headsup for Azure pipelines: It looks like you need to specify the url, because localhost resolves to ::1. The script will just continue to run without resolving: wait-on will poll infinite, because 127.0.0.1 isn't answering. Solution: update the wait-on part to `wait-on tcp:127.0.0.1:6006`, please make sure that you tests are served correctly on that url too.